# How to use ssl connection with mydumper?

Tags: mysql, ssl

The current version actually support ssl since [May 3, 2018][https://github.com/maxbube/mydumper/commit/2a922f4d8a598fbdb5786868f8150e3cc88c266f], but I can't use the ssl connection.
I tried with params `--ssl 1`, `--ssl true` or `-s 1` and didn't work
`--help` don't show any information about ssl

I'm using version bb963448d1183e933cc540b52a62a1da27a92117, I compiled it in ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Can you include the relevant code in the body of your question? External links are problematic. It's important to keep your question as self-contained as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The ssl support is optional in compilation.

[Contributor answer](https://github.com/maxbube/mydumper/pull/36)